# How did Talbot survive being shot seemingly unharmed?

Tags: uncharted

During the Syria section of Uncharted 3, the team are cornered by Talbot and his men. Charlie pretends to be still under Talbot’s mind control, then shoots Talbot in the chest allowing Nate and team to get away. Minutes later however, Talbot shows up seemingly unharmed and attempts to kill Charlie.

The dialogue after this scene treats this event as a mystery with Charlie insisting he shot Talbot, but as far as I can tell it is never mentioned again. I was expecting this to be foreshadowing of some supernatural origin for Talbot, such as that he’s a Djinn or an immortal John Dee, but no such backstory is forthcoming and he displays no special immunity to bullets at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game's head writer and creative director [Amy Hennig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amy_Hennig) posted some info about this on her Twitter account. In short, he was likely wearing a bulletproof vest when he was shot and used the opportunity to try to gain an advantage.

> Hey - I saw people are also confused about Talbot getting shot, and
> disappearing... maybe I can elaborate a little...
>
> Marlowe's crew is supposed to be a highly-trained clandestine
> organization, with roots stretching back to Elizabeth I and earlier.
> Sort of like CIA/MI6 secret intelligence service type ops... so the
> idea is they have lots of means to confound their enemies like a
> secret arm of the CIA or MI6 might, for example. Like Cutter says,
> manipulating their enemies through espionage, deception, fear.
>
> This is based on real-life clandestine ops, and "the art of
> deception". Groups like the CIA really used magician's tricks as well
> as drugs, etc. to trick and frighten their enemies. So - you can
> assume there's a rational explanation behind these mysteries... e.g.,
> **a bulletproof vest, an escape rope/wire**, whatever--which looks
> "magical" but has a rational explanation, just like a magician's
> trick.
>
> Magic, tricks, deception, illusion, perception vs. reality - these are
> themes throughout the game. Abra-godd*mn-cadabra.
>
> <sub><sup>https://forums.penny-arcade.com/discussion/comment/21051198/#Comment_21051198</sup></sub>

Alas, she seems to have deleted the original posts, but multiple people have independently referenced them, so they seem to be legit comments.